# How to use AJAX and php Laravel to send a contact form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a contact form using Laravel 5.5 and Mailtrap.io which works fine. however, I am trying to make the contact form send without reloading the page to do this I am using AJAX. However, I have no idea how to connect AJAX with Laravel and Mailtrap.io.

This is the Form I have created.

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'success') }}">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
@endif
<form action="{{ url('contact') }}" method="POST" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="primary-form">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-768"><input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" placeholder="First Name" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-768"><input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Last Name" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-766"><input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="E-mail Address" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input type="text" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone Number" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea-6"><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></span>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right:10px;">
            <p class="clearfix">
                <button type="submit" class="button button-simple btn-submit mt-30">SEND</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The AJAX method I am using to send the page without reloading the page.

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name=last-name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var bodyMessage = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, email:email, phone:phone, bodyMessage:bodyMessage},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });
});
```

This is my ContactController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function postContact(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email'] );

        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('jafar@calmcollective.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Contact Details');
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Your E-mail was sent! Allegedly.');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');

        return redirect('contact');

    }
}
```

I have spent hours on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get any error on the request? Don't forget to pass also the form token on your ajax

Comment: `url:this.action,data:$(this).serialize(),`?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi True I forgot to add the form token via ajax. I don't get an error. I don't know how to get the data variable from my Ajax function to my contactController so I can send the contact form via mailtrap.io.

Comment: Jafar, have you setup a route for the ajax to pass to the controller?

Comment: @Option Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@PostContact');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer at your original question, I can see an error in the spelling of the method of your `ContactController` :

```
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@PostContact');
```

should be

```
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@postContact');
```

Then in your javascript, you should listen for the form submit event, not only the submit button clicked event, and add the csrf_token to the data :

```
$("form.wpcf7-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val(); // The CSRF token
    var first_name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name=last-name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var bodyMessage = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{_token: token, first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, email:email, phone:phone, bodyMessage:bodyMessage},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });
});
```

Finally, you should return a success parameter in your ContactController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function postContact(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email'] );

        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('jafar@calmcollective.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Contact Details');
        });

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Your E-mail was sent! Allegedly.'], 200);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great but the bodyMessage variable is not showing when I receive the message on Mailgun. Should I still use {{ bodyMessage }} to display the message?

Comment: Yes, in your `emails/contact.blade.php` you can use `{{ $bodyMessage }}` (with the `$` at the beginning of the variable name) to display it

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the form is reloading because your using a click handler on a submit button hoping to prevent default, What you have: `$(".btn-submit").click(function(e)`, change click to submit: `$("#form-id").submit(function(e)`.

Secondly why not send FormData object instead of all this:

```
e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name=last-name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var bodyMessage = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, email:email, phone:phone, bodyMessage:bodyMessage},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });
```

Try this:

```
e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.querySelector('#form-id');
    var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       data:data,
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });
```

In your php you'll have to access the variables by the name of the form fields.
**EDIT**
To be clear to access the variables in php script using the request object do this: `$request->input('nameOfInputfield')`, to access all the values as an array use `$request->all()`

Comment: Hi Thank but how do you access the variable in my ContactController.php file?

Comment: `$request->all()` gives you everything as an array, you can also access then seperately using `$name = $request->input('name')`

Answer (score 0):

I use to do it with jquery and jquery form plugin:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
[jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: oh ok can I put {{ url('contact') }} insead of contact.php?

Comment: Plugin serialize all form data and send to action value and have callback function both on success and error event. All you need to do is define as ajaxform and use ajaxsubit funcion on submit event. I will write an example to show you it is as simple as sound.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving the Ajax the Attribute `dataType: "json"`?
You should be able to get the parameters then.

If you did that you will also need to return a json to the ajax request according to ajax documentation, which would be something like that:

```
return Response::json([
    'success' => 'Your E-mail was sent! Allegedly.',
    'alert-class' => 'alert-success'
]);
```